# Scala Syntax Specification mismatch if-else with one line expression end by semicolon?

Tags: scala, syntax, compiler-construction, grammar

I'm learning [Scala Syntax Specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html).

Confused by the `if-else` syntax:

```
  Expr1             ::=  ‘if’ ‘(’ Expr ‘)’ {nl} Expr [[semi] ‘else’ Expr]
                      |  ...
```

How could it match below if-else with one line expression end by semicolon ?

```
if (true) // \n
  println(1); //\n
else //\n
  println(2); //\n
```

Notice there're 4 lines and each followed by a `'\n'`. I have these questions:

1. When the 1st `;` after `println(1)` match `semi` before `else`( `[[semi] ‘else’ Expr]` ), how to match the 2nd `'\n'` after `;` after `println(1)` ?
2. How to match the 3rd `'\n'` after `else` ?
3. How to match the 2nd `;` and the 4th `'\n'` after `println(2)` ? Since `if-else` don't match any `;` or `'\n'` at tail.

Comment: Your code snippet is not parsable https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LS4fpFYmTbqTtro9k1kfGA

Comment: @DmytroMitin, remove `'\n'`, I just want to highlight the newline token

Comment: There are four `'\n'`. You can edit your question.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, which part is confusing for you ?

Comment: The code snippet making it parsable. Or is it intended that the snippet is not parsable?

Comment: I think it is ok now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are being confused by thinking that all newlines must match the `nl` token. That is not correct.

Newlines are *in general* simply treated as whitespace. There is a very long subsection on newlines in the Lexical Syntax chapter [section 1.2 *Newline characters*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) which explains in detail, when, *exactly*, a newline character is an `nl` token and when it isn't.

Only the first newline character in your example is an `nl` token, the other three are just whitespace.

Comment: yes you're right, there's  different states inside scala compiler when it process the newline token.

Comment: Yeah, simply put: not every newline *character* is a newline *token*.

Answer (score 0):

in Scala, `semicolon ;` doesn't exist (is ignored)

if-else statement is so simple with brackets as :

```
if (true) {
  "\n" // this will be returned
  println(1) // this will be ignored
  "\n" // this will be ignored
} else {
  "\n" // this will be returned
  println(2) // this will be ignored
  "\n" // this will be ignored
}
```

or, you can use without accolades, but the statement must be writed in one line:

```
if (true)
  "\n" // this will be returned, can not have another line here
else 
  "\n"
```

without comments: `if (true) "\n" else "\n"`

[More about if-else in Scala](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_if_else.htm)